# Internet speed checking app for Android

Tags: android, internet, connection-speed

I'm looking for an internet speed checking app for Android that:

1. Does not try to make any connections when it isn't explicitly run by the user.
2. Does not load itself in the background... ever.
3. Does not collect any data.

[V-Speed Speed Check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.speedtest.android) looked good (reliable results) at first, but - according to the firewall - it is attempting to make internet connections even when it not opened by the user.

Then [Speed Check Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.speedspot.speedanalytics) looked good, but they collect all sorts of data.

Prefer gratis and open-source, but open to all recommendations.

Comment: Long time ago that I tried such an app (and it ate 50% of my monthly volume in just 10 minutes =:-0). So I cannot tell which one meets the criteria. But as usual, I have a [little app list on that](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_372) so you know at least which ones *not* to take (those with too many monitor-icons on their line ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use Speedtest by Ookla (http://www.speedtest.net) on my iPhone and iMac. Works great. Measures upload and download speeds. Their web page says its available for android too. To my knowledge it never does anything until you start it. It logs your result but only locally. If wrong on that please let me know.

Comment: Thanks.  I used to use Speedtest as well.  I honestly don't recall why I stopped using it.  I thought there was something that didn't meet my criteria, but I just don't remember anymore.  Some downsides, at least for the Android version, are that you can't specify the server to use and you can't control how much data will be transmitted during testing.  But neither of those are deal-breakers.

Comment: I don't know about Android version but you can choose server on the Mac version.

Comment: John, could you please [edit] your answer and include a link to the app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just did it. hope this meets your needs.

Comment: I also use it, here is the link for Android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest&hl=en